# Prove that $\frac{R}{J(R)}$ is a domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

I have to prove the following: if $R$ is a unital ring ( non necessarily commutative), that is connected (the only idempotents are 0 and 1) and artinian, then $\frac{R}{J(R)}$ is a domain.

My attempt:
Since $R$ is artinian, it is semiperfect. Then $\frac{R}{J(R)}$ is semi-simple and idempotents of $\frac{R}{J(R)}$ lift modulo $J(R)$. Since $R$ is connected, it follows that also $\frac{R}{J(R)}$ is connected. Then I'm stuck. Any hint would  be appreciated. 
Thank you !

Comment: We have $J\left(R / J\left(R\right)\right) = 0$ (this is well-known). Since $R / J\left(R\right)$ is Artinian (because $R$ is Artinian), this shows that $R / J\left(R\right)$ is semisimple. Thus, [the Artin-Wedderburn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin–Wedderburn_theorem) shows that $R / J\left(R\right)$ is a product of finitely many matrix rings over division rings. But you have shown that $R / J\left(R\right)$ is connected (whatever this means -- I only know this word for commutative rings). I suspect this should greatly reduce the options for the matrix rings (and their number).

Comment: Thank you very much, I totally forgot about that theorem. For the conclusion: the ring of matrix on a division ring $D$ always contains the matrix (0,1),(1,0) (I wrote the first and the second row in case $n=2$) which is an idempotent element. Then, since $\frac{R}{J(R)}$ is connected, and since that matrix is neither 0 nor 1, it implies that the matrix cannot exist. So is it just a product of division rings? Thank you for the help !

Comment: Yeah, except the matrix you wrote isn't actually idempotent :)

Comment: Ahah yes sorry ! But there is also the problem that the product of integral domains is not and integral domain :( So maybe I have to find something to reduce the number of matrix in the product.

Comment: Well, a product of at least two nonzero rings always has nontrivial idempotents.

Comment: Oh yes thank you! I think I got the answer now!

Comment: Feel free to post it as an answer to close the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, then:
after the Artin-Wedderburn theorem, $\frac{R}{J(R)}$ is a product of $n$ matrix ring over division rings. Since the product of at least 2 rings contains non trivial idempotents, (i.e. $(1,0)$), and since $\frac{R}{J(R)}$ is connected, it must be $n=1$. Now, for $N\geq2$ (where $N$ is the size of the matrix), every matrix ring over a division ring contains the non trivial idempotent $(0,0),(0,1)$. Again, by connectivity of $\frac{R}{J(R)}$, we have that $N=1$, so $\frac{R}{J(R)}$ is division ring, hence a domain.